# ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Ljava.lang.String

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting

I get this error->

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

From  the code pasted below.

```
public class LoginAttemps extends Setup {
    public void testSearchCountry() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        ReadExcelDemo readXls = new ReadExcelDemo();
         List dataList = readXls.getData();
         for (int i = 1; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
             String[] testCase = new String[5];
             String[] test = (String[]) dataList.get(i);
             String countryName = test[0];
             String countryDesc = test[1];
             driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).clear();
             driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys(countryName);
             driver.findElement(By.id("searchButton")).click();
             String str = driver.findElement(
             By.xpath("//h1[@id='firstHeading']/span")).getText();
             System.out.println(countryDesc);
             Assert.assertTrue(str.contains(countryName));
         }
   }
}
```

I think the issue is with `String[] test = (String[]) dataList.get(i);`

But I am not sure about resolving this exception.. Any clues?

Answer (score 9):

You can not cast "String" into "Array of Strings".

You can only put a string into a slot within an array.

What you can do is:

```
    String theString = "whatever";
    String[] myStrings = { theString };
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I believe you trying to convert **List to an Array**, therefore your "issue line" should be the following:

```
String[] test = (String[]) dataList.toArray(new String[dataList.size]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause: element at "i" position is of type string. However you are trying to cast it into array of string.

Direct Solution: remove [] from both sides i.e. change from:

```
String[] test = (String[]) dataList.get(i);
```

To:

```
String test = (String) dataList.get(i);
```

This will work if your List will not contain array of any type.

Answer (score 0):

thankyou Guys. Yeah I am trying to cast a List Objects to String Arrays.  I found the issues. Corrected code.

```
    public void testSearchCountry() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        ReadExcelDemo readXls = new ReadExcelDemo();
         List dataList = readXls.getData();
        String[] test = new String[dataList.size()];
         for (int i = 1; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
             String[] testCase = new String[5];
             test[i] = dataList.get(i).toString();
             String countryName = test[0];
             String countryDesc = test[1];
             driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).clear();
             driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys(countryName);
             driver.findElement(By.id("searchButton")).click();
             String str = driver.findElement(
             By.xpath("//h1[@id='firstHeading']/span")).getText();
             System.out.println(countryDesc);
             Assert.assertTrue(str.contains(countryName));
         }
   }
```

and it worked.